# iPerf claims it's using same TCP window size when given -w with different requested size but rate is different

Tags: linux, tcp, iperf

I am testing a network device bandwidth with `iperf 2.0.10` and seeing weird issues.

When I am using command `iperf -c [dst_ip] -w [window size]` and specify window size with different values (250 KByte and 300 Kbyte), iperf outputs `TCP window size: 432 Kbyte (Warning requested 250 KByte)` and `TCP window size: 432 Kbyte (Warning requested 300 KByte)`, which looks like it's using same TCP window size of 432 regardless what I actually requested for. However the rate difference here is beyond 20%.

Does iPerf actually use the Window size as requested or it's using 432 Kbyte as it claims?  If it's using 432 Kbyte in both case why would there be a difference at rate?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying operating system is setting the window size and you should see the same performance for both runs.  The output with -e from the client might provide some insights.

Comment: To be clear, the operating system can adjust the requested size up or down.